# consulta composta no sql

Tags: sql, mysqli

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e preciso fazer uma consulta composta. Vou colocar uma foto das minhas tabelas, para poder explicar melhor:

[image: Imagem contendo o modelo relacional do banco de dados]

Como mostrado na imagem, eu tenho a tabela reserva que tem uma relação ManyToOne com a tabela diária, que também possui uma relação ManyToOne com a tabela prato, que por sua vez se relaciona com a tabela cardápio. O que eu preciso é filtrar todas as reservas que referenciam uma diária com uma data 'X' e que por sua vez referenciam um prato que esteja relacionado com um cardápio de id 'Y'.

Eu desenvolvi essa solução:

`select * from Reserva where diaria_id in (selec id from Diaria where data = 02-02-2020 and prato_id in (select id from Prato where cardapio = 1))")`

Mas por ter pouca experiência e base, fiquei me perguntando se essa é realmente a melhor forma de fazer isso ou se essa consulta pode acarretar em algum trabalho desnecessário na hora de implementar esses filtros.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor opção depende de um monte de coisas, vale sempre usar o [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) em diferentes versões da query e comparar os resultados. Outro caminho – fundamental de você conhecer – é usar `JOIN` (mais detalhes em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/). Por exemplo:

```sql
SELECT Reserva.* 
FROM Reserva 
    INNER JOIN Diaria 
    ON Diaria.id = Reserva.diaria_id
    INNER JOIN Prato
    ON Prato.id = Diaria.prato_id
    INNER JOIN Cardapio
    ON Cardapio.id = Prato.cardapio
WHERE Cardapio.id = 1
```

Comment: Entendi, não conhecia o EXPLAIN, vou dar uma estuda para entender como funciona. Eu já conhecia o inner join mas estava em dúvida se devia ou montar a query usando ele ou do jeito que fiz. Mas vou estudar um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento dele ! Mas de qualquer jeito obrigado pela pela ajuda e atenção. Eu estudo por conta própria e sempre tenho essas dúvidas sobre qual a melhor abordagem pra resolver um problema, então ter ajuda de outra pessoa é ótimo